PG::UndefinedTable: relation "csv_uploads" does not exist error despite migrations running successfully
I'm encountering an issue where I receive the following error in my Rails application:
vbnet
Copy code
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "csv_uploads" does not exist
LINE 10:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"csv_uploads"'::regclass
^
This happens when I try to access the index page of my CsvUploadsController, which is supposed to display a form for uploading CSV files. The table csv_uploads is not being found in the database, even though:
The migration to create the table (CreateCsvUploads) appears to have run successfully.
I have confirmed that the migration status shows as up for the CreateCsvUploads migration.
I've tried running rails db:migrate, rails db:reset, and rails db:drop db:create db:migrate, but the issue persists.
The csv_uploads table exists in my PostgreSQL database when I check with psql using \dt.
Here’s the code for the migration:
ruby
Copy code
class CreateCsvUploads < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :csv_uploads do |t|
      t.string :file_name
      t.string :upload_type
      t.text :validation_errors, default: "[]"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

I’m using PostgreSQL as the database, and I'm running Rails 7.x.
Things I’ve already tried:
Ran migrations multiple times with rails db:migrate.
Reset the database using rails db:reset and rails db:drop db:create db:migrate.
Checked table existence using psql (\dt shows csv_uploads).
Cleared the Rails cache and restarted the Rails server.
Checked my schema.rb file, and the table is listed there.
My questions:
Why am I still encountering the PG::UndefinedTable error?
Is there any other step I might be missing to ensure the table is being recognized in the Rails app?
Any suggestions on debugging this further to identify why the table isn't being recognized in the application?
I would appreciate any help or suggestions! Thanks in advance!
CSV Upload:
class CsvUpload < ApplicationRecord
  # Add any validations or relationships here if needed
  validates :file_name, presence: true
  validates :upload_type, presence: true  # Change this to :upload_type
end

CSV controller
class CsvUploadsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @errors = []
  end

  def create
    uploaded_file = params.dig(:csv_upload, :file) # Safely fetch the file parameter
    type = params.dig(:csv_upload, :type)         # Safely fetch the type parameter

    unless uploaded_file&.respond_to?(:original_filename)
      flash[:error] = 'No file uploaded or invalid file format.'
      redirect_to csv_uploads_path and return
    end

    if uploaded_file.original_filename.ends_with?('.csv')
      csv_data = CSV.parse(uploaded_file.read, headers: true)
      @errors = validate_csv(csv_data, type)

      if @errors.any?
        CsvValidation.create(validation_errors: @errors.to_json)
        redirect_to show_validation_errors_csv_uploads_path
      else
        redirect_to csv_uploads_path, notice: "CSV processed successfully."
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Only CSV files are allowed.'
      redirect_to csv_uploads_path
    end
  end

  def show_validation_errors
    @validation_record = CsvValidation.last
    @errors = @validation_record ? JSON.parse(@validation_record.validation_errors) : []
  end

  private

  def validate_csv(csv_data, type)
    case type
    when "Purchase Order"
      PurchaseOrderCheck.new.validate(csv_data)
    when "Order"
      OrderCheck.new.validate(csv_data)
    when "Product"
      ProductCheck.new.validate(csv_data)
    when "Supplier"
      SupplierCheck.new.validate(csv_data)
    else
      ["Invalid type selected."]
    end
  end
end


Add your controller code and csv_upload model code to the question.

Don’t see any code in your index method that matches the error you  reference

Have you ensured that it isn't an environment issue? For example are you running the migrations in development but not in production?

Also with this type of problem your code is actually near irrelevant. What really matters is to try to isolate the issue and see if you can reproduce it. For example though a test or the Rails bug reporting template usually it's just a simple human error somewhere.
